laser reader and vba excel
Using a laser reader and the KEYDOWN event of excel vba, which key on the keyboard is associated with a laser reader?
I need to use  Excel VBA keydown event for a textbox object but I use a laser reader and I would like to know which keycode argument is  input from a laser reader corresponds to.
I'm using a Motorola Symbol
In Excel VBA there is following routine for KEYDOWN event:
Private Sub TextBox1_KeyDown(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)
End Sub

I need to know value for argument KEYCODE using a laser reader.

do you mean a barcode scanner? is this scanner programmed to send a carriage return (enter key) after the code is read?

Yes, it it programmed to send a carriage return.

Wouldn't it be KeyCode = vbKeyReturn then ?

I asked this question because I don't know if the physical key on the ENTER keyboard is equivalent to the enter given with the barcode scanner.

Put Debug.Print KeyCode inside the event handler and see what happens when you scan something?

Using a barcode scanner generates the same keycode value as physically pressing the enter key on the keyboard.I have solved.
